# Integrating YouTube Data API v3 iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

I am trying to integrate the YouTube Data API v3 for iOS into my project.  In the end all I want to do is upload videos from all instances of the app to a company owned youtube channel, and get the URL to be able to embed the videos in a website.  I can't figure out how to integrate the client library for iOS though.  I get compile errors, or ARC issues that I can't figure out how to resolve.  The files are found here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short this is what I did:

In my project I added the GTLYouTube_Sources.m, GTLCommon_Sources.m and GTLNetworking_Sources.m. 
Make sure that Build Phases -> Compile Sources the compiler flag '-fno-objc-arc' is set for these three files. This should fix your ARC issues.
You may need to set some search paths in your Build Settings if the compiler complains that it can't find a file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues but with a combination of google's page + a youtube tutorial I was able to get things working, I still don't know how to search yet but here are my notes on the subject:

This file points in the right direction - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

This video is better - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7m3qCsQBEE

As per my comment on the video stream - "

I did this tutorial and receive 9 linker errors referencing the derived data folder and that "file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)" but have "Standard Architectures" selected in the Build Settings for the project (armv7,arm64). This is using Xcode 6 but I can try on Xcode 5.1.1 if needed (though I don't think this issue will abate as it supports the 64bit architecture as well. Going into the GTL Project and selecting the GTLTouchStaticLib and changing the architecture over to Standard removed the linker errors and the build succeeded! https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6tc6t33r5k5021/Screenshot%202014-10-10%2012.08.00.png?dl=0﻿”

API Calls may still with 401 despite having an API key due to a known issue - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770#makechanges to fix is remove the bundle ID from the google console.

Comment: could you build for device ?.. i am able to run on simulator but getting linker error for device @Stuart P.

Answer (score 0):

i'm giving an **updated answer** for this question. so it can be helpfull to community.

**NOTE:- GTL is converted to GTLR . GoogleLibrary is updated. i Recommend to use cocoapods because it will be simple.**(according to me) here is the [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#cocoapods) for this migration

1) create pod file for your project. by `pod init` & `pod install` in your terminal. it will create blank pod installation.(ignore if you have done already)
2) add these pod library name in pod file.
here is the some [services](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/master/GoogleAPIClientForREST.podspec) that can be useful

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube' //here '.../YouTube' is the service. you can use ".../Caledar' ,".../Translate" or which you want.
pod 'GTMAppAuth'
```

3) add these headers (i recommend to create Prefix Header '.pch' for your project.)

```
#import <GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.h>
#import <AppAuth/AppAuth.h>
#import "GTLRYouTube.h" //here you can change double quotation ("...") with (<...>) if this throws the error "library not found".
```

4) this step is optional.. 
select your project target & go to `build settings`. and search for `OtherLinkerFlags` and add `$(inherited)`

**NOTE:-** `if you can use Firebase to use google's service it will be more easy.(i've tried it and it was simple than google developer console. this is my personal opinion.)`